# Process hung in linux desktop

Tags: linux, centos, hung

I have a hung linux desktop situation I browsed over internet and found Ctrl+Alt+F1. It opens a terminal i could kill a process from the terminal but

HOW TO LOG BACK FROM THAT TERMINAL TO THE X SESSION ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTRL-ALT-F1 puts you on the first virtual terminal. Typically X runs on the 7th, so CTRL-ALT-F7. Your distro may vary, I haven't used CentOS in many moons, so try CTRL-ALT+ each of the F keys in turn if that doesn't work.

Comment: If you feel the answer is correct please accept it!